# Ajax data insert into database not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to build a comment system for my website using Ajax, jQuery and PHP. My site has the lot of queries, how can I submit comments every query separate?

**Ajax code**

```
 $(document).ready(function()
   {
   $("#comq").click(function() {
       var comment=$("#comment").val();
               var qid=$("#qid").val();
       $.ajax({
        cache:false,
        type:"post",         
         url:"jquery.php",
data:{comments:comment, qid:qid},
        success:function(data)
        {
    $(".cmt").html(data);
        }
     });
   });
  });
```

when I submit the comments, comments only inserted but  query (qid) not inserted in DB (database table)

**php code**

```
 if(isset($_POST["comments"])){         
    $comment=$_POST['comments'];
    $qid= $_POST['qid'];
    $reslt_user= mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM tbl_users,`queries` where id='".$_SESSION['id']."' AND  qid= '".$qid."'");
    $row_lat_lng= mysqli_fetch_array($reslt_user);
       $stmt = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO comments set uid='".$_SESSION['id']."',comments='".$comment."',reply='".$reply."', qid= '".$qid."' ");
```

**Html code**

```
     <div id="comments" class="cmt" >
    <input class="commentbox"id="comment"name="comments"placeholder="Comment 
               Here" maxlength="50">
    <input type="hidden"id="qid "name="qid">
     <button type="button" id="comq" name="compost" class="butn2" value="submit">
    </button>
                        </div>
```

How to post comments as per queries (how to insert)?

Comment: You are open to SQL injections, parameterize your query. Check the return of your query call for errors.

Comment: Where do you define `$reply`?

Comment: @chris85 Please Give  me more clarification on this

Comment: Read more about [Prepared Statements in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  no need reply now i  will remove that

Comment: You haven't SET a value on `#qid` it has `name` and `id`, but no `value`, hence it will be empty/undefined.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie where to i have to set #qid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this line here,

```
<input type="hidden" id="qid "name="qid">
                        ^^^^
```

- Misplaced closing `"` for *id* attribute.
- `value` attribute is missing from the *hidden* input element.

So the *hidden* input element should be like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="qid" name="qid" value="SOME VALUE" />
```

---

**Sidenote:** Learn about [**prepared statement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) because right now your queries are susceptible to SQL injection attack. Also see [**how you can prevent SQL injection in PHP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: No Still same issue And let me know how can i give value whats is the use

Comment: @MadhuMunna If you don't give any `value` attribute, then with this `var qid=$("#qid").val();` you would get `qid` as *undefined*. Did you change the closing `"` for *id* attribute as well? Do `alert(qid);` inside your js code and see what it is showing.

Comment: where can i put the alert in ajax

Comment: @MadhuMunna Right after `var qid=$("#qid").val();` put `alert(qid);` to check whether you're getting expected value or not. Also, in place of `SOME VALUE` in the `value` attribute, put your desired value there.

Comment: getting  an alert box  (empty)  when i was submitted the comment

Comment: Regardless, why do you have that `qid` element at all in the INPUT? The ID should be generated by the database, and pushed back to be attributed to the actual comment when it is shown.
(No need to have that qid when submitting a comment, but you might wanna have it when showing the comment to be able to identify it on edits, deletions etc.)
I'm guessing your whole approach is a bit wonky, and that you don't really understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @MadhuMunna That should not happen, see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/theyg56o/2/). `value` attribute and the associated value must be missing. Check this first.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul sorry still not  working  main problem qid not inserted into db